# String index out of range even though I've circumvented it in my code

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I'm creating a function which returns a list of elements without any elements of the same value next to each other. However, I experience this error even though I don't see how it could happen?

```
if s[i + 1] != s[i] or s[i - 1] != s[i]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

My program is as follows:

```
def unique_in_order(s):
    arr = []
    for i in range(0, len(s)):
        if i == 0 or i == len(s):
            arr.append(s[i])
        else:
            if s[i + 1] == s[i] or s[i - 1] == s[i]:
                pass
            else:
                arr.append(s[i])
    return arr
```

Comment: `i == len(s)` won't ever evaluate to `True`. Try `i == len(s)-1`

Comment: I feel stupid, thank you so much!